# How to get to compare one column between two sheets to tell info in one sheet that is not in the other in Numbers

Tags: numbers

What we are trying to accomplish is:

1) We have a list (spreadsheet) of all of last years clients.

2) We have a list (spreadsheet) of this years clients.

3) We need numbers to subtract out all of this years clients from last years clients so we know who all is yet to have come.

How do we accomplish this on the current version of Numbers (6.2.1 I think) on MacOS 10.15.3?

Comment: Assuming that the client cells have the EXACT same spelling and information between the two columns, it is still a complicated process. Comparing and reducing can be an extensive task with spreadsheets.

Comment: How many clients/lines are there?

Comment: They do have the exact same spelling as when the client comes in the software imports them from last year to this year; then we export both years to XLSX file.

Comment: Around 700 clients @nohillside

Comment: Also if this is too difficult/impossible-(or nearly) in Numbers, I am open to other solutions.

Comment: Copy each list in a sheet just containing the names, sort alphabetically and export as CSV. Then open Terminal and run ˋdiffˋ on both files

Comment: @nohillside if say "Doe, John" is on line 1 of NEW, and line 3 of OLD will the diff still count them? (Because one list is way shorter than the other most names won't be on the same line)

Comment: Use match() to find if an item in list A exists in list B, if it exists it will give position number and an error if not.

Comment: Sure. I can make a full answer out of it tomorrow, will need some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way you can do this is through a formula using if(), iferror(), and vlookup() functions and also, if you wish, the Filter feature in Numbers.

Assuming you have the names of this year's clients in a table called "Clients 2020" and those of last year in "Clients 2019", you can identify the names of those that are yet to come this year with the formula shown in the picture below:

[image: formula for clients]

Here is a text version of the same formula if you wish to copy & paste it from here:

```
= IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Clients 2020::B$2:B$21,1,0),0)=0,B2,0)
```

This formula lookups the name of the client in the cell on its left within the specified cells in the table called "Clients 2020". If the name is there, it returns "0". If not, it returns the name of the client. You may have to modify the formula a bit depending on the name of the table which has this year's clients and the exact cell addresses.

If you also wish to show only the yet-to-come (2019 only) clients as a list, you can then use Numbers' Filter feature. You can access this feature through the Organize option on the right in Numbers' toolbar at the top as shown in the picture below:

[image: filtered client list]

The filter shown in the picture above "filters" out any rows in the table "Clients 2019" whose "2019 only" column is equal to 0.

If you would like to copy part or all of the filtered table elsewhere for further processing for any reason, select all the names (and, for example, the No column or any additional column you may have if you like) and press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then select a cell in a new table (in a new sheet or file in Numbers if you also like) and then press <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (keyboard shortcut for "Paste Formula Results" menu option). These commands, when applied to a filtered table, will only copy & paste the cells you selected from the filtered table.

Hope these help!

Answer (score 1):

So, just hacked this together using match() and iferror(). Hope it helps.

```
iferror(match(B4,E4$:E$8,0),”Not in list”)
```

[image]

You can edit to work across sheets but the concept is there.